# Fetch data to and from a website

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I have read the documentation about [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html). But I can't understand how to use the data parameter. The example:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

is not working: `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

But what I understand from it is that I can name some options/parameters and give them a value. But my question is: **How I know which parameters are in the website? Or how can I know them?**

I have "played" with:

```
response =urllib2.urlopen(url)
html=response.read() 
print html
```

To read the website but I didn't succeed to fetch my data after trying some values that I thought they would work. In the website there is a button to choose file, and some radio buttons to select to get an output. **How can I do it?**

The webpage I am trying to fetch is [this one](http://genome.crg.es/software/geneid/geneid.html).

Comment: The website has to have a public-facing API for you to be able to POST values to it.

Comment: Do the steps manually in your browser and look at the requests that it sends (use a network sniffer or builtin browser capabilities to see the requests).

Comment: @arusidante how I know if they have an API? I could enter manually the results but then how I get them from a .cgi website? I can't use your  option Sebastian. But thanks for proposing a solution

Comment: @Llopis: how do you which parameters to use then?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you are asking about how I know which parameters to use I tried inspecting the element and getting the name of the element I do modify manually. I was referring to use a sniffer to do get the parameters. But I don't know how to use the browser capabilities to do so.

Comment: Answering your question would be much easier if you provided a working of example of a site in which a manual request works and a urllib2 request fails.

Comment: @Ryne The problem is that I don't know how to do a urllib2 request. That is why I ask how to know which parameters use, but it seems that the website I am trying to request doesn't have an API.

Comment: Looks like you *can* make the requests manually, you just don't know how to inspect the requests sent over network e.g., in Chrome goto `Tools -> Developer tools -> Network`. You can ask how to do it in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `urllib2` to drive forms and the like will lead to frustration.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize is a good place to start.

http://www.sciprogblog.com/2012/01/scraping-data-with-python.html this guy has laid out lots of useful information. This won't answer your questions but it should lead you down the right paths.

Good luck.

Comment: Nice links! I will try to use them